# Let $P$ be a polytope of dimension $d$. Then for some $v \notin$ aff($P$), the pyramid $v \ast P$ has dimension $d+1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polyhedra, convex-geometry, polytopes

> Let $P$ be a polytope of dimension $d$. Then for some $v \notin$ aff($P$), the pyramid $v \ast P$ has dimension $d+1$.

I’m looking for a straightforward argument to prove this statement. All the arguments I’ve come up with so far involve embedding $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$, and analyzing the number of linearly independent vectors. I’m hoping to find a simpler explanation, if possible.

Here are the definitions of the relevant terms in the course I’m doing:

$\cdot$ A polytope is defined as the convex hull of a finite set of points in some $\mathbb{R}^d$. Alternatively, it is a bounded polyhedron - defined as the intersection of finitely many closed halfspaces in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
$\cdot$ Let $P \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a (possibly empty) polytope of dimension $< d$. For a point $v \in \mathbb{R}^d \setminus \text{aff}(P)$, we define the pyramid $v \ast P$ with apex $v$ and base $P$ as the convex hull of $P \cup \{v\}$.

Comment: What's the definition of polytope that's being used that's not already in $\mathbb{R}^d$? Why is embedding an "extra" step? Also, what's the definition of $*$ in $v * P$? Thanks!

Comment: You might be overthinking this.  If $P$ is already in $\mathbb R^d$, then it is easy to show that $v \in \mathbb R^{d+1}$ with a non-zero coordinate in the axis "beyond" $\mathbb R^d$ will give you the pyramid over $P$ that you want.  I'd like to see the problem statement laid out in the body of your Question, not just in the title.

Comment: @hardmath surely dim$(v \ast P) \geq \text{dim}(P) + 1$, as $v \notin \text{aff}(P)$. But is there a simple reason why dim$(v \ast P) \leq \text{dim}(P) + 1$? The statement looks obvious, but I can’t prove it yet.

Comment: @hardmath Also I feel like perhaps I’ve misunderstood your point. The construction in your argument certainly gives a pyramid, but how does it implies that the dimension of the pyramid is dim$(P) + \ 1$?

Comment: My construction would take place inside $\mathbb R^{d+1}$, so the dimension of $(v*P)$ is at most $d+1 = \dim P + 1$.  Perhaps the setup of your problem is a little more abstract, that is, $P$ is embedded in *some* Euclidean space with $d$-dimensional $\operatorname{aff}(P)$.  Then of course to get something *not* in $\operatorname{aff}(P)$ the ambient space must be higher dimensional.  But then it is possible to pick $v\not\in \operatorname{aff}(P)$.

Comment: So the difficulty seems to come down to this.. where does $P$ exist?  If it lives only in $\mathbb R^d$, then (being a $d$-dimensional polytope) we would have $\operatorname{aff}(P) = \mathbb R^d$, and there would not be any way to choose $v\in \mathbb R^d$.  We really need to work in a higher dimensional space to get what you want (a $d+1$-dimensional polytope/pyramid).

Comment: There’s no particular restrictions on the dimension of ambient space where $P$ is in (except that it’s greater than $d$ of course, so that $v \notin \text{aff}(P)$ could be picked). Say the ambient space has dimension $d+2$, how do I know that the dimension of the pyramid is still just at most $d+1$? (This is the claim in the first sentence of your second comment. I’d like to have some elaboration on that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if we review a few (standard) definitions that are missing from the Question statement, the sought "straightforward argument to prove" the quoted claim will quickly materialize.

Note the definition of a polytope added to the Question:

> A polytope is defined as the convex hull of a finite set of points in some $\mathbb R^d$.

This is satisfactory, provided one knows how to define the *convex hull* of a finite set $S$ of points in a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^d$, or more generally in a vector space $V$ (or in an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space)).  If one knows what it means for a set (in a vector space) to be [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#Definitions), then one can say the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Definitions) of (finite) $S$ is the smallest convex set that contains $S$.

In any case our polytope $P$ will be a convex set in whatever vector space $V$ where it exists.  As we are about to see, that space $V$ plays a critical role in proving the desired claim.

The notation $\operatorname{aff}(P)$ presumably means the [affine hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_hull) of $P$, namely the smallest affine subset of $V$ that contains $P$.  The affine subsets of $V$ are precisely the *translates* of its linear (vector) subspaces.  That is:

$$ \operatorname{aff}(P) = \{w\} + W $$

for some vector $w \in V$ and some linear subspace $W \subset V$.

The *dimension* of $P$ is the same as the dimension of $\operatorname{aff}(P)$, which is defined to be the dimension of the linear subspace $W$ of which it is a translate.

If the dimension of $P$ is $d$, then in order to pick $v \in V \backslash \operatorname{aff}(P)$, $V$ will have to be of dimension greater than $d$.  In other words, if $V$ were the same dimension as $\operatorname{aff}(P) \subset V$, then they would have to be equal as affine subsets, and we would be unable to choose $v\in V$ that is not in $\operatorname{aff}(P)$.

Thus we will assume $\operatorname{dim} V \gt d$ and choose $v \in V \backslash \operatorname{aff}(P)$.  Then, since $\operatorname{aff}(v*P)$ is larger than $\operatorname{aff}(P)$, the dimension of pyramid $v*P$ must be greater than $d$, so its dimension is at least $d+1$.

Why is the dimension of $v*P$ not more than $d+1$?  It suffices to show that $\operatorname{aff}(v*P)$ is contained the translate of a linear subspace of $V$ of dimension not more than $d+1$.  We have all the facts necessary to show this. Since:

$$ P \subset \operatorname{aff}(P) = \{w\} + W $$

we have the pyramid:

$$ v*P \subset \operatorname{aff}(v*P) \subset \{w\} + W' $$

where $W'=\operatorname{span}(\{v-w\} \cup W)$ results from $W$ by extending its basis with vector $v-w$ (so that $v\in \{w\} + W'$).  Hence $\operatorname{dim} W' \le d+1$ and the claim is proved.

Answer (score 0):

When you say a set is of dimension $n$ it means that it can be embedded at least in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
The idea of a dimension is that of this  exercise: you are in $\mathbb{R}^d$; for a point here $v$ not in $\mathbb{R}^d$  we can join $v$ to $P$ by a segment in fact this segment (vector) is the added dimension if you want, this is the generalisation of moving from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I'm not sure your first sentence says precisely what you intended.  A set that is contained in $\mathbb R^n$ is of dimension *at most* $n$.  The OP supplies some definitions in its final sentences, but significantly omits defining "dimension $P$" and "aff($P$)", terms that are important to rigorously proving what is claimed.

Comment: Yes it may be ambiguous but, if something of dimension $d$ there are precisely $d$ independent vectors defining it, so i said it can be embedded (considered) in $\mathbb{R}^d$ by a natural corresponding basis. For here $P$ is of dimension $d$ by vectors $v_1,…,v_d$ its affine hull is $V=vec(v_1,…,v_p)$ a point $v$ not in $V$ defines a new dimension vector $\vec{vp}$, $ p\in P$ so that pyramid $v\cup P$ is of dimension $d+1$. All this is in finite dimensions of course.

Comment: Note that the fewest vertices that a polytope of dimension $d$ can have is actually $d+1$.  This minimal case is a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).